# Calling Outlook Ribbon function "Home" -> "Move" -> "Move" -> "Other Folder" in VBA script

Tags: vba, outlook

I frequently use "Move -> Other folder" to move emails to my branched archive system. Drag and drop is not usefull with my lengthy archive, and I like the similarity between the send to onenote and "Move -> Other folder" submenu's. However, having to click "Move", then scroll to "Other folder" is annoying.

Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to directly open the "Other folder" submenu from within a VBA macro? If so, how exactly can I call this function? As I already created a bunch of VBA scripts to transform mails into diff types of tasks/calender items with the press of a button, the latter function call would be a great addition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook VBA can simulate a button press with ExecuteMso.

Hover over the button where you would add it to the ribbon, you will see the text includes "MoveToFolder".

```vb
Private Sub ExecuteMso_MoveToFolder()

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso

    Dim oMail As mailItem
    Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Debug.Print oMail.subject
    
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MoveToFolder")
 
End Sub
```